# wpf checkbox selected when clicked outside of label

Tags: wpf, checkbox

It seems my checkbox width is stretching to the extents of grid cell in which it is contained. So if you check way to the right of the checkbox label it still toggles the value. Is there a way to make the checkbox only toggle when the label or checkbox is clicked without hardcoding a width value for the checkbox?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you set your column definition width to "Auto" then the column will be resized to fit the `CheckBox`.

However, that might ruin your layout.

An alternative is to wrap the `CheckBox` in a `StackPanel`.

```
    <Grid Margin="10,10,10,10" Name="grid1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Text="Hello"/>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <CheckBox Content="Click Me"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <Button Grid.Column="2" Content="Press Me"/>
    </Grid>
```

As you can see from the first screen shot, the bounding box of the `CheckBox` is now just around the check and label as opposed to being the full width of the column as shown by the second.

**Correct behaviour:**
[image: correct behaviour]
**Incorrect behaviour:**
[image: incorrect behaviour]

Answer (score 5):

The default `HorizontalAlignment` of CheckBox is `Stretch`. Try setting it to `Left`/`Right`/`Center`.

Answer (score 3):

It may really stretch that wide. Try to apply some background to the CheckBox - this will show you how wide it is in reality. Also play with HorizontalAlignment.